# Cant insert data into database 000webhost

Tags: database

I am connected to the 000webhost database and it is all running and works but cannot insert data it give me the not Not Inserted! (echo I wrote) 
I really don't know why i cant upload to the database I'm connected to it but wont send data to the DB I have all the loggin info hidden everything else is normal!

```php
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "************", "*********", "*************");

    if (!$con) {
        echo "Not Connected!";
    } else {
        echo "Connection Succeful.";
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'id5456491_emails')) 
    {
        echo 'Database not selected!!';
    }

    $Name = $_POST['username'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql_store = "INSERT INTO emails1 (ID,Name,Email) VALUES (NULL,'$Name','$Email')";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $sql_store);

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql_store)) {
        echo 'Not Inserted!';
    } else {
        echo "INSERTED!ss";
    }
    //header("refresh:2; url=referal.php");
 ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Do+Hyeon" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>B.F.B Hvac</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    #logo {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        border:5px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%
    }

    #content {
        text-align: center;    
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(61, 60, 59);
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;        
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    #about {
        background-color:rgb(61, 60, 59);
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        color:white;
    }

    #cool {
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        color: blue;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    #heat {
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        color: red;
        font-size: 30px; 
    }
    #p1 {
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        color: black;
        font-size: 30px; 
    }


    #login-form {
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .ll {
        background-color: grey;
        height: 20px;
    }

    ::placeholder {
        color:black;
    }

    .ll:hover {
        border-color: grey;
        height: 25px;
        color: white;
        ::placeholder {
            color:white;
        }
    }

    #btn {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    #btn:hover {
        border-color: black;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="head">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="quote.php">Quote</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="referal.php">Referal</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.goodmanmfg.com/product-registration">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="specials.html">Specials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BFB-Heat-Air-703964289638814/">
            <img src="BFBlog.jpg" id="logo">
        </a>

        <h1 id="about">Referal</h1>

        <form action="dbh.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your email">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Referal email">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div id="foot"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code below, it looks like you are doing the same `INSERT` twice.

```php
$sql_store = "INSERT INTO emails1 (ID,Name,Email) VALUES (NULL,'$Name','$Email')";

// the first INSERT
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $sql_store);

// the second same INSERT again!!
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql_store)) {
    echo 'Not Inserted!';
} else {
    echo "INSERTED!ss";
}
```

Do you have any `UNIQUE constraint` on the table, eg: Name, Email? If yes, I suspect the first `INSERT` was successful, but the second one failed due to `UNIQUE constraint` violation. You may change your code like this & retry:

```php
$sql_store = "INSERT INTO emails1 (ID,Name,Email) VALUES (NULL,'$Name','$Email')";
// only 1 INSERT
$success = mysqli_query($con, $sql_store);

// check for INSERT return status
if (!success) {
    echo 'Not Inserted!';
} else {
    echo "INSERTED!";
}
```

Comment: @GregMyers If this helps, why not mark this as answer then? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

dont use auto_increment for the primary key..
add manually, use max(primary_key)+1
it work for me

Comment: What in the question makes you suspect that this is the answer?